# PHP shell_exec() script running from CPanel terminal but not from ajax POST call

Tags: bash, permissions, python, php, godaddy

On my website, I have a javascript function that has a POST ajax call to a PHP file on the server (a GoDaddy VPS running CentOS 6), which executes a python script via shell_exec() and returns the output.

Javascript function:

```
function submitdivsheet()
{
    $.post("test.php", {}, function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
    }); 
}
```

PHP script: test.php

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python3.6 test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Python script: test.py

```
import sys
print("This is the output")
```

When I try to run the php file from the bash terminal on CPanel, there are no issues,
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AOrV.png). However, upon running the javascript function, only an empty string is output to the console. I'm not sure why it would only run on the CPanel terminal, but I suspect it could be a permissions issue somewhere. How can I fix this issue?

NOTE: This works fine on both the server and from the POST call if shell_exec() is not present. It seems that shell_exec is causing the problem.

---

EDIT:
Upon changing the PHP script to:

```
<?php print shell_exec('echo $PATH'); ?>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yv77.png) is the output.

Comment: My first guess is that it's a PATH issue.  Can you please [edit your post](https://superuser.com/posts/1473340/edit) to include the output of this `test.php`: `<?php print shell_exec('echo $PATH'); ?>'  Does it show a PATH at all?  Is your `python3.6` in that path?  If either answer is no, you'll need to specify the full path to `/where/ever/you/have/python3.6`

Comment: @JimL. added! It shows a path, but python3.6 is not in that path.

Comment: As my previous comment says then, you'll need to update your `test.php` file to include the full path to `python3.6` in your PHP code.  Possibly the full path to `test.py` also.

Comment: @JimL. Thank you! This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing environment values when invoking python from the web server that are present in your shell. Candidates are `PATH` and the variables mentioned in the python man page.

Try this:

```
env -i python3.6 test.py
```

You will likely get some error messages that will hopefully point to the problem. Then try variables that are present in your shell environment, like:

```
env -i PYTHONHOME=$PYTHONHOME python3.6 test.py
```

Add all necessary environment variables. When this works, add them to the call to the script. When calling the script, you have supply the actual values for the variables, you can't refer to them as `$PYTHONHOME`.

Comment: when I run "env -i python3.6 test.py", the terminal returns "python3.6: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then one of the missing things is an entry in the `PATH`. Find out where it is (`type python3.6`) and add it to the PATH.